# Como habilitar Null-Safety no Flutter sem quebrar o projeto?

Tags: flutter, dart

Como habilitar `Null-Safety` no Flutter sem correr o risco de quebrar o projeto?

Vi muitos relatos de pessoas que ao habilitar aparecem problemas de compatibilidade em certas bibliotecas.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente, algumas bibliotecas de terceiros ainda não foram atualizadas para o Null-Safety, o que faz o projeto quebrar. Mas existe um processo que pode ser feito de forma a minimizar as chances disso ocorrer.

Pelo terminal, execute o seguinte comando:

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

Este comando irá listar todos os pacotes do seu projeto e se existe alguma versão compatível com o Null-Safety. Verifique se todos os pacotes do seu projeto já têm versões compatíveis e, caso tenham, basta executar os seguintes comandos para fazer o update no arquivo pubsec.yaml e para usar as respectivas versões dos pacotes:

```
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
dart pub get
```

Com a atualização dos pacotes, pode ser necessárias algumas correções, portanto faça isso primeiro antes de continuar. Após corrigido, execute o seguinte comando para migrar seu projeto ao Null-Safety:

```
dart migrate
```

**Importante:** Caso tenha alguma biblioteca que ainda não tenha suporte ao Null-Safety, consulte se existe uma Issue aberta no repositório Git e discussões recentes, neste caso, aguarde a atualização, ou, se o pacote se tornou descontinuado (não tenha recebido atualizações a muito tempo), considere alterar o mesmo por algum similar que tenha suporte ao Null-Safety.

Comment: Fonte: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide